# How can i rewrite URL in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How can i rewrite URL in nginx
http://www.example.com/dir/mobil.php
To
http://www.example.com/dir/mobil.php?action=add_form&page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest google for such a question. Quick search with exact your terms brought this up:

https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/